# Collect MAC address of Zabbix agents

Tags: triggers, zabbix, mac-address, inventory, auto-registration

I would like to get the MAC address of the Zabbix agents **(both Windows & Linux)** and automatically fill in the inventory of the particular hosts.

I've used the key **system.hw.macaddr** to do this, but I think the key is only supported in Linux hosts. Still, the MAC address is not available in the inventory field of the Linux host.

What I need actually is to **get the MAC address automatically when the host has registered** and also to **trigger an alert when any host tries to change the MAC address** on their own.

Comment: yes, system.hw.macaddr is available on Linux only https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/items/supported_by_platform for Windows you need to use a UserParameter https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/userparameters

Comment: I managed to collect from Linux hosts but still finding it difficult in windows hosts.
Please help me resolve this. How should I mention the UserParameter?